# Stripe and Rails 4: This customer has no attached payment source

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I am running in to very sporadicly occurring errors upon subscribing to a plan using Stripe.

Upon hitting the subscribe button, sometimes the user and subscription gets created and the data I get back from Stripe (stripe_id, stripe_subscription_id, card_last4 etc.) is being properly saved.

Every other time I am running in to the following error:

`Stripe::InvalidRequestError in SubscriptionsController#create`

`This customer has no attached payment source`

```
when 400, 404
  raise invalid_request_error(error, resp, error_obj)
```

**SubscriptionsController#create**

```
class SubscriptionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authorize

  def create
    @user = current_user

    customer =  if current_user.stripe_id?
                  Stripe::Customer.retrieve(current_user.stripe_id)
                else
                  Stripe::Customer.create(email: current_user.email)
                end

    # Get the credit card details submitted by the form
    token = params[:stripeToken]

    subscription = customer.subscriptions.create(
          source: token,
      plan: "monthly"
    )

    @user.attributes = {
      :stripe_id => customer.id,
      :stripe_subscription_id => subscription.id,
      :card_last4 => params[:card_last4],
      :card_exp_month => params[:card_exp_month],
      :card_exp_year => params[:card_exp_year],
      :card_brand => params[:card_brand]
    }

    @user.save(:validate => false)

    redirect_to root_path
  end

end
```

**subscription.js.coffee**

```
jQuery ->
  Stripe.setPublishableKey($("meta[name='stripe-key']").attr("content"))

  $('#payment-form').submit (event) ->
    $form = $(this)
    # Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
    $form.find('button').prop 'disabled', true
    Stripe.card.createToken $form, stripeResponseHandler
    # Prevent the form from submitting with the default action
    false

stripeResponseHandler = (status, response) ->
  $form = $('#payment-form')
  if response.error
    # Show the errors on the form
    $form.find('.payment-errors').text response.error.message
    $form.find('button').prop 'disabled', false
  else
    # response contains id and card, which contains additional card details
    token = response.id
    # Insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
    $form.append $('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(token)

    $form.append $('<input type="hidden" name="card_last4" />').val(response.card.last4)
    $form.append $('<input type="hidden" name="card_exp_month" />').val(response.card.exp_month)
    $form.append $('<input type="hidden" name="card_exp_year" />').val(response.card.exp_year)
    $form.append $('<input type="hidden" name="card_brand" />').val(response.card.brand)
    # and submit
   $form.get(0).submit()
  return
```

Again, sometimes the payment works, sometimes it raises the error.

(I am aware of the other questions about this topic but no one seemed to have those sporadic occurrences)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps add `debugger` under your create and see what exception and where comes up?

```
class SubscriptionsController <     ApplicationController
  before_action :authorize

  def create
    debugger
    @user = current_user

    customer =  if current_user.stripe_id?
                  Stripe::Customer.retrieve(current_user.stripe_id)
                else
                  Stripe::Customer.create(email: current_user.email)
                end

    # Get the credit card details submitted by the form
token = params[:stripeToken]

    subscription = customer.subscriptions.create(
      source: token,
  plan: "monthly"
)

    @user.attributes = {
      :stripe_id => customer.id,
      :stripe_subscription_id => subscription.id,
      :card_last4 => params[:card_last4],
      :card_exp_month => params[:card_exp_month],
      :card_exp_year => params[:card_exp_year],
      :card_brand => params[:card_brand]
    }

    @user.save(:validate => false)

    redirect_to root_path
  end

end
```